# Flask-SQLAlchemy sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError no such table 'comic'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am having some issues with flask-sqlalchemy.

I have my model.py file

```py
from app import app, db
from config import (SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_ECHO,
                    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = SQLALCHEMY_ECHO

class Comic(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Comic'
    comicId = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    comicName = db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True,nullable=False)
    comicAuthor = db.Column(db.String(100),unique=False,nullable=True)
    comicPrice = db.Column(db.Numeric(20,2),unique=False,nullable=True)
    comicDescription = db.Column(db.String(500),unique=False,nullable=True)
    comicStatus = db.Column(db.String(50),unique=False,nullable=True)
    comicImage = db.Column(db.String(250),unique=False,nullable=True)

    def returnComic():
        Comic.query.all()


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    userId = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String(25),unique=True,nullable=False)
    passWord = db.Column(db.String(10),nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(25),unique=True,nullable=False)

class Favorite(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Favorite'
    userId = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.userId'),nullable=False,primary_key=True)
    comicId = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('comic.comicId'),nullable=False)
```

Inside of my app.py file I have all of my routes

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import model

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    results = model.Comic.returnComic()
    return render_template("index.html", results=results)

@app.route('/overview')
def overview(page=1):
    results = db.session.query(comics).all()
    return render_template("overview.html", results=results)


@app.route('/overview/details')
def details():
    return render_template("detail.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   db.create_all()
   app.run(debug=True)
```

I also have a config.py file

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI= "mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/scraper"
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION = False
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
```

The error arises when I go the the index route, I would like to display some data from the database inside the HTML file, but it gives a stack trace

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: Comic
[SQL: SELECT "Comic"."comicId" AS "Comic_comicId", "Comic"."comicName" AS "Comic_comicName", "Comic"."comicAuthor" AS "Comic_comicAuthor", "Comic"."comicPrice" AS "Comic_comicPrice", "Comic"."comicDescription" AS "Comic_comicDescription", "Comic"."comicStatus" AS "Comic_comicStatus", "Comic"."comicImage" AS "Comic_comicImage" 
FROM "Comic"]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1283, in _execute_context

    self.dialect.do_execute(

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 590, in do_execute

    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app

    response = self.handle_exception(e)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise

    raise value

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise

    raise value

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\app.py", line 12, in index

    results = model.Comic.returnComic()

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\model.py", line 21, in returnComic

    Comic.query.all()

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3319, in all

    return list(self)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3481, in __iter__

    return self._execute_and_instances(context)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3506, in _execute_and_instances

    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1020, in execute

    return meth(self, multiparams, params)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection

    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1133, in _execute_clauseelement

    ret = self._execute_context(

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1323, in _execute_context

    self._handle_dbapi_exception(

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1517, in _handle_dbapi_exception

    util.raise_(

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_

    raise exception

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1283, in _execute_context

    self.dialect.do_execute(

    File "C:\laragon\www\Proftaak\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 590, in do_execute

    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: Comic
    [SQL: SELECT "Comic"."comicId" AS "Comic_comicId", "Comic"."comicName" AS "Comic_comicName", "Comic"."comicAuthor" AS "Comic_comicAuthor", "Comic"."comicPrice" AS "Comic_comicPrice", "Comic"."comicDescription" AS "Comic_comicDescription", "Comic"."comicStatus" AS "Comic_comicStatus", "Comic"."comicImage" AS "Comic_comicImage" 
    FROM "Comic"]
    (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Now I have googled around a bit, and it seems the issue lays in that the database is queried first before the models can be made?

also is it supposed to remake the database whenever I use flask-run ?

Comment: you need to migrate, run flask db migrate -m 'creating new models' that will create a file in migrations/versions, then run fladk db upgrade

Comment: also is it supposed to remake the database whenever I use flask-run ? No, the DB iss persistent, thats why you need to handle the migraations properly, first time you create it flsk will understand it is empty and write SQL to ccreate those tables

Comment: running the command `flask db migrate -m ` gives me a no such command `db` found error

Comment: well your db does not exist :) are you setting up SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI?, you have it in your config, try export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=YOURURI (on unix)

Comment: also check you set the FLASK_APP variable, I don't remember how it gets the config, it is a bit of a pain in the beggining but you'll get the hang of it

Comment: managed to fix the database URI, seems you need to pass the app.config settings BEFORE instantiating the SQLAlchemy object. running the `flask db migrate` command does insert a alembic_version into my db, also i set my FLASK_APP variable to app.py.  now the only thing i need is to get my classes from model.py inside of my database when running flask db migrate

Comment: you are on a good track, if flask ddb migrate does not throw any error, then check migrations/versions you should have a file starting with a weird string there with the code to migrate, don't need to touch it, all you need to do is run flask db upgrade

Comment: yea i ran that command and now i have the classes from model.py modeled inside of my database along with the alembic_version corresponding to the migration version

Comment: then your error should disapear, start the app and give it a try!

Comment: by the way, every time you cchange your data models run flask db migrate and check the output produced, it does some funny things, that will keep your up always in sync with the db, it is very important

Comment: That fixed it!, getting the data displayed from the database correctly now. if you would like to add the solution as a separate answer I can up vote it and check mark it. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the answer for the record:

You need to migrate your db so that it has the tables you will be querying

1. Make sure your SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI is set for flask:

   ```
   export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/scraper"
   ```
2. make sure flask can see your app

   ```
   export FLASK_APP=path-to_your_app:app #might also be main or wsgi if you are using that
   ```
3. Prepare a migration file:

   ```
   flask db migrate -m 'starting database'
   ```

   This will create a file in migrations/versions, something like 4232hg44242gv24424242_starting_database.py, ccheck that it does what you want it to do (create tables etc)
4. run the migration (once, this will set the alembic_version in your DB to be 4232hg44242gv24424242 [the prefix of your migration file] and it will be used to keep track of at what migration your db is [meaning you can upgrade or downgrade and have several DBs at different points and they can get migrated easily])

   ```
   flask db upgrade
   ```

You should be done, start your app and try again.